# composer asking oauth token for download public repo

Tags: php, github, composer-php, dependency-management

My PHP project has a dependency on a nice library [php-sql-query-builder](https://github.com/nilportugues/php-sql-query-builder). However, this library has a bug. So I fork the library from it github source to my github account at https://github.com/mmuhasan/php-sql-query-builder and fix the bug in a branch named "[dev-where-bug-fix](https://github.com/mmuhasan/php-sql-query-builder/tree/dev-where-bug-fix)". Then I updated my my project composer file as following:

```
....
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/mmuhasan/php-sql-query-builder"
    }
],
"require":{
    "nilportugues/sql-query-builder" : "dev-where-bug-fix"
},
....
```

When I run `composer update` it ask for a oAuth token as follows:

```
Could not fetch https://api.github.com/repos/mmuhasan/php-sql-query-builder/contents/composer.json?ref=3dca30b0eaee835783fa61286a51dda425cd3838, please create a GitHub OAuth token to go over the API rate limit
Head to https://github.com/settings/tokens/new?scopes=repo&description=Composer+on+LAPTOP-056S12EK+2018-03-27+1845 to retrieve a token.
```

Since my fork is in public, and I want it to be public, why composer is asking token. Any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 23):

This has nothing to do with public vs. private GitHub repositories. You're hitting [GitHub's API rate limit](https://developer.github.com/v3/rate_limit/).

From [Composer's troubleshooting guide](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#api-rate-limit-and-oauth-tokens):

> ### API rate limit and OAuth tokens
>
> Because of GitHub's rate limits on their API it can happen that Composer prompts for authentication asking your username and password so it can go ahead with its work.
>
> If you would prefer not to provide your GitHub credentials to Composer you can manually create a token using the following procedure:
>
> 1. [Create](https://github.com/settings/tokens) an OAuth token on GitHub. [Read more](https://github.com/blog/1509-personal-api-tokens) on this.
> 2. Add it to the configuration running `composer config -g github-oauth.github.com <oauthtoken>`
>
> Now Composer should install/update without asking for authentication.

Comment: This is bit awkward as the only dependency I have in my project and with the first hit, it reach rate limit. I have tried with `composer update nilportugues/sql-query-builder' and still the same result. Is it something to do with my github account?

Comment: I doubt this has anything to do with your GitHub account or your repository. [GitHub only permits 60 unauthenticated requests per IP address per hour](https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting). Are any other tools using the API? Are there other users on your network using it?

Comment: I am the only one in the network using this in the network. and if I remove the `Repositories' from the composer.json file, all works fine. Make any sense?

Comment: With saying 60 requests, when I am downloading a repo (through composer), if that repo contain more than 60 files will it hit the rate limit. Will each file (or any other search) be part of the count of rate limit?

Comment: @MdMonjurUlHasan Maybe you are not *individually* hitting the rate limit, but you + everyone else masked behind the IP the request is coming from [eg: shared host/server] is collectively hitting the rate limit, and the only way to distinguish yourself from the rest is with the OAuth token.

Comment: I just installed your library without any problems using `"repositories"` and `"require"` stanzas that match what's in your question without having to add a token. You must have hit the API limit somehow.

Comment: @MdMonjurUlHasan, since the anonymous rate limit is hourly you should be able to try again without adding a token in 20 minutes or so (assuming you haven't been hammering the API this whole time).